# How to access session attribute in Play frame work using scala?

Tags: scala, playframework

I tried to access session attribute using scala and play frame work. but could n`t get success.  here is the code

User.scala

```
 def login = Action { implicit request =>
        val newLoginForm = loginForm.bindFromRequest()

            newLoginForm.fold(

            hasErrors = { form =>
               Redirect(routes.Users.loginUser()).
                flashing(Flash(form.data) + 
                    ("error" -> "Fill user name and Password"))
                },
            success = { implicit newUser =>
                if(User.findUserBydb(newUser.uname,newUser.pass)){

                    Ok(views.html.pages.page_one()).withSession("mysession"-> "jeff@example.com")

                }else{
                   Redirect(routes.Users.loginUser()).
                    flashing("error" ->"Invalid Login")
                }    
            }
            )
    }
```

view ---- > page_one.scala.html

```
    @import play.api.Play.current
@import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._
@import play.api.mvc.Session
@import play.api.mvc.Request


@index("Hi"){
    <h2>
      Welcome  @request.session.get("mysession")
    </h2>

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the session on the view, you will need to add the implicit request `(implicit request: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader)`. So your code will be something like

```
    @import play.api.Play.current
    @import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._
    @import play.api.mvc.Session
    @import play.api.mvc.Request
    @()(implicit request: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader)

    @index("Hi"){
       <h2>
         Welcome  @request.session.get("mysession")
       </h2>

    }
```

Comment: I think you can add the `implicit` directly to the `Session` object instead: `@()(implicit session: Session)`.

Comment: I don't think it can work using the session as implicit with the current code. It would need to be declared.
However, we already have the request object in the first line:
`def login = Action { implicit request =>`

Comment: I was talking about the view code and not the controller. As documented [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaSessionFlash#Flash-scope), you can implicitly add `Flash` scope as a parameter. I suppose you can do the same with `Session` scope.

Comment: Well, the `Flash` parameter is kind of a special object. You need to use `Result.flashing` to make it implicitly available. Perhaps I didn't explain my solution well enough. The view uses what you declare in the `Action` as a parameter (e.g.: `@(testObject: MyObject)`) or what you already have declared implicitly as the second parameter at the head declaration (e.g: `@()(implicit testObject: MyObject)`). If @marcospereira still have doubts about this, perhaps I can extend this with another comment.

Comment: Carlos, here is what I'm talking about: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f30fba1c385303f0b34d. In other words, just like you can implicitly pass a `Flash` object to the view, you can do the same with a `Session`. Notice that `flashing` is just a idiomatic way to set values in `Flash` scope, just like `withSession`.

Comment: you can import all the implicits by specifying this on the first line of your template `@import play.mvc.Http.Context.Implicit._` source: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/java/play/mvc/Http.Context.Implicit.html